# Is the space $C(0,1)$ dense in Sobolev space $H^2(0,1)$? And $C^\infty_c(\Omega) = C^\infty_0(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

I have two questions:

1. Is $C(0,1)$ dense in $H^2(0,1)$? Yes or no? Could you give me a proof or an explanation?
2. $C^\infty_c(\Omega) = C^\infty_0(\Omega)$? from the different textbooks, I see that the spaces $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ consists of all those functions in $C^\infty(\Omega)$ that have compact support in $\Omega$. But it seems that $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ has the same meaning. the little $c$ means compact support? or it depends on the set $\Omega$?

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Your question is phrased without any information or context, this does not 
match many [users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To 
prevent that, please [edit] the question to include your thoughts and the work you have done so 
far to solve the problem. For some basic information about writing math on MSE see: 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $C(0,1)$ isn't even contained in $H^2(0,1)$...

Comment: thanks. can you give some details? in addition, what about the second one?

Comment: The second one depends on your definitions of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ and $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $H^2$? Hardy space or Sobolev space?

Comment: both of these spaces are Sobolev spaces

Comment: from the different textbooks, I see that the spaces $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ consists of all those functions in $C^\infty(\Omega)$ that have compact support in $\Omega$. But it seems that $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ has the same meaning. the little $c$ means compact support? or it depends on the set $\Omega$?

Comment: I. Melissa, your question has been put on hold as a result of community moderation. Don't take it personally, this happens often to new users who have not yet learned what is expected from questions. The links in the comments above give you pointers, of what you can do. Your first edit will place the question on a reopening queue, where users will evaluate the new edition of your question. So, make that first edit count.

Comment: I don't know what motivated the users who vote to put this *on hold*, but my speculative guess is that to some the question looks like an attempt to get somebody to do your homework. To dispel such thoughts you could add some context to it, such as: why you want to know this? what are your own thoughts? et cetera. If it were up to me, such expectations would be necessary only on questions about calculus level and below. But, for reasons of site politics it applies to all the questions.

Comment: Last but not least, welcome to Math.SE. This was a bit unfortunate beginning, but don't let it discourage you. This site is a wonderful resource. After you gain a bit of familiarity with these do's and do-not's you will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of subscript $0$ in $C_0^\infty$ depends on where you see this notation. Some authors use it to mean "compact support". Others use it to mean "vanishing on the boundary", and if they need notation for smooth functions with compact support, it's $C_c^\infty$.

The space of **continuous** functions, such as $C(0,1)$, is not contained in $H^2$, so one can't really talk about it being dense there. But it's true that its intersection with $H^2$ is dense in $H^2$, since it contains all smooth functions with square-integrable second derivatives, and those are dense in $H^2$.